# IIS Virtual directory causes JQuery errors in Fancybox

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Fancybox works perfectly on my example.html, but when I make a virtual directory in IIS with the default page as example.html, I get jquery syntax errors returned in line 1 of all js files.

Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0; Trident/4.0; SLCC1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; Media Center PC 5.0; Tablet PC 2.0; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30618; OfficeLiveConnector.1.5; OfficeLivePatch.1.3)
Timestamp: Tue, 3 Aug 2010 16:07:07 UTC

Message: Syntax error
Line: 1
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: http://www.example.com/fancybox/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.2.pack.js

Message: Syntax error
Line: 1
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: http://www.example.com/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.1.js

Message: Syntax error
Line: 1
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: http://www.example.com/fancybox/transitions.js

Comment: Are the paths correct? Can you navigate directly to the JS files from the browser and view their contents?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, making the includes absolute instead of relative corrected the problem. (I swear I tried that before posting)